# Google Calendar erroneously identifies Opera as mobile

Tags: opera, google-calendar

I am a happy user of Google Calendar across different machines, browsers. However, when I am working with Opera 12.16 on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, opening Google Calendar will automatically select the mobile version of the calendar, which is annoying.

How can I fix this problem?  Is this an identification issue? GMail and Google Search just show up normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try changing your "User Preferences" to always show the Desktop version of a website.

1. If you type `opera:config` in the address bar you will be presented with the "Preferences Editor".
2. Expand the "User Prefs" option and copy the below into the "Custom User Agent" field:

**For Mac/Linux:**

> Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X; U; en) Presto/2.2.15
>   Version/10.10

**For Windows:**

> Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10

Finally, scroll to the bottom, click Save and then OK on the next dialog to confirm the changes.

[Source](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=421831)

Comment: Nice, good to know.

Comment: If I change it to `Opera/9.80 (Linux; Ubuntu 12.04; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.10` it also correctly identifies as Ubuntu.

Comment: Forget about this last remark, then my original problem reappears :)

Comment: So you're saying it doesn't work if you change the information to `Linux; Ubuntu 12.04`?

Comment: Exactly, I get the mobile version back.

Comment: Oh ok. As long as it works with the original line :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [the Google Calendar's desktop URL](https://www.google.com/calendar/render) instead of [the mobile version's URL](https://www.google.com/calendar/m).

Comment: The link from GMail inbox automatically redirects me to the `/m` variant.